# Работа с RGBA с помощью увеличения канала

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, pytorch

Мне нужен такой gan, чтобы он мог работать с четырехканальным изображением. Прочитал информацию о том, что необходимо просто указать в input слое о том, что моё изображение будет четырёхканальным. Но с этим возник вопрос. Будет ли корректно работать сам gan или нужны дополнительные действия? Если есть какие-то примеры или статьи об этом, скиньте пожалуйста.

Comment: Так вы попробуйте сначала. Не получится что-то - тогда и спрашивайте. Не вижу особых препятствий.

Comment: Более того, там можно вообще сложить (друг на друга) два RGB изображения и получится 6 каналов.  Аналогично с выходом. Код программы, разумеется, придется корректировать (и обучение проводить заново).